Kullback-Leibler divergence monotonically increasing
Let $\mu,\nu$ be finite measures supported everywhere, not necessarily probability distributions. Define $KL(\mu\mid\nu)= \sum_i\mu_i\ln\frac{\mu_i}{\nu_i}$ for measures.
For a given mass $m$, is it true that $\mu=\frac{m}{\sum_i\nu_i}\nu$ minimizes $KL(\mu\mid\nu)$ over all $\mu$ satisfying the constraint $\sum_i\mu_i=m$?
If $\mu, \nu$ were probability distributions this would just amount to the standard fact that the KL divergence is zero iff $\mu=\nu$. My intuition says this should be true, somehow generalizing the result for probability distributons, but I am struggling to prove it in general.
The gradient vector is $\frac{\partial}{\partial{\mu_i}}= \ln(\mu_i/\nu_i)$, and suffices to show that for any distribution $\mu$, the inner product $\nabla KL\cdot (\alpha \nu - \mu)\leq 0$ where $\alpha$ is the scalar $(\sum \mu_i)/(\sum \nu_i)$. It have been able to prove this in some special cases.
I have shown that it is equivalent to say that
$$\frac{\sum_i\mu_i\ln\frac{\mu_i}{\nu_i}}{\sum\mu_i}\geq \frac{\sum_i\nu_i\ln\frac{\mu_i}{\nu_i}}{\sum\nu_i}$$
Beyond this point I am stuck.
I have tried using Jensen's inequality as in the usual proof for probability distributions and the AM-GM inequality but I haven't solved it.

Let $n= \sum_i \nu_i$, and note that $\frac\mu{m}$ and $\frac\nu{n}$ are probability distributions.  We can compute
\begin{align*}
D_{KL}\left(\frac\mu{m} \middle\| \frac\nu{n}\right)
&= \sum_i \frac{\mu_i}{m} \log \frac{\mu_i/m}{\nu_i/n} \\
&= \frac1m\sum_i \mu_i\log\frac{\mu_i}{\nu_i} + \log\frac{n}{m} \\
&= \frac1m D_{KL}(\mu \| \nu) + \log\frac{n}{m}
\end{align*}
So for fixed $m$ and fixed $\nu$, minimizing $D_{KL}(\mu \| \nu)$ over $\mu$ is equivalent to minimizing $D_{KL}\left(\frac\mu{m} \middle\| \frac\nu{n}\right)$ over probability distributions $\frac\mu{m}$.  So the divergence is uniquely minimized when $\frac\mu{m} = \frac{\nu}{n}$ as desired.
